# How to limit digits in a logfile?

Tags: python, limit, digits, logfiles

I have a Python program that takes voltage readings and puts them into a logfile for later use. It works fine except the voltage readings have too many digits. I tried "%.5f" % in my print logfile line but I get an error "float argument required, not file". Here is the pertinent part of my program:

```
voltsdiff = adc.readADCDifferential01(4096, 8)
logfile = open('logfile.txt', 'a')
print >> logfile, time(), (voltsdiff-2.534)/0.03422
logfile.close()
```

I'm getting numbers like 1052.37821133599778 and 1051.75680765443765 and I only want like 1052.

Comment: If you want only a few digits, use `'{:.5f}'.format((voltsdiff-2.534)/0.03422)`.

Comment: I used '{:.0f}'.format((voltsdiff-2.5434)/0.03422) # Works great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
int(round(1051.75680765443765)) # 1052
int(round(1052.37821133599778)) # 1052
```

Answer (score 0):

```
volt = (voltsdiff-2.534)/0.03422
int(volt) # will get rid of decimals
```